# This site cant be reached error while I am loading sitecore 8.2 client

Tags: iis, setup

It was working fine few days back, but suddenly my local environment ends up with below error. I have tried installing new instances of sitecore as well but no luck.

+**Adding Windows Network Diagnostics troubleshooting Report**

```
The device or resource (sitecore82) is not set up to accept connections on port "The World Wide Web service (HTTP)".
```

Url: http://sc82local/sitecore/login

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please check the logs and share more detailed information? Also, check IIS and ensure it is up and running, as well as Application Pools.

Comment: Hi @ViniciusDeschamps, there are no entries in logs. Seems the request is not at all hitting the website. The site and App pool are up and running.

Comment: looks like there some socket error on your computer. try by reset windsock. run this cmd -  `netsh winsock reset`

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat, tried the suggested command but still the same issue. The problem is happening if I install a new instance of sitecore as well

Comment: @ManideepYechuri: if you execute `ping sc82local` in a Command Prompt window, is the domain resolving to your local IP (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo, Yes it is showing 127.0.0.1 and ping is successful

Comment: This can happen if VPN is turned on

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve the issue by executing below commands

**netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=aa.bb.cc.dd** (where aa.bb.cc.dd is the IP address that we have to remmove)

**netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0**

**iisreset**

Answer (score 0):

The request is probably not hitting your sitecore site. I would probably -

- restart IIS
- Clean all application pools
- check hosts file if it contains entry with which the website is being accessed
- check binding on the website if the hostname is correctly mapped to the site
- check site definitions in the website if the hostname gets resolved to a valid sitecore site or not.

Comment: I tried all the above options and everything looks good

1. Restarted IIS and verified
2. Recycled all available Application pools
3. Entry is there in hosts file
4. No other bindings as of now except the default one
5. Site definition is also fine

I am testing on a plain instance without any modifications done on top of that instance.